# VBScript/HTA Application - Running multiple programs at once chosen by user

Tags: vbscript

So here is what i am wondering about boys and girls - first of all i am a complete noob to this, LITERALLY just starting so don't go too hard on me. I have a bunch of code i wrote, to make a .HTA application:

```
> <html> <head>
> 
> <script type="text/vbscript">
> 
> Dim objShell Sub Button1_OnClick()
> 
> if box2.checked AND box1.checked then
> 
> Set objShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
> objShell.Run("""%programfiles(x86)%\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe""")
> Set objShell = Nothing
> 
> Set objShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" ) objShell.Run("cmd.exe")
> Set objShell = Nothing
> 
> elseif box1.checked then
> 
> Set objShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" ) objShell.Run("cmd.exe")
> Set objShell = Nothing
> 
> Elseif box2.checked then
> 
> Set objShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
> objShell.Run("""%programfiles(x86)%\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe""")
> Set objShell = Nothing
> 
> 
> End If End Sub
> 
> 
> </script> </head> <body> <font face=Calibri> Check the program you
> would like to run! <br> Available programs to run for now: <br> <input
> type="checkbox" name="box1">CMD <br> <input type="checkbox"
> name="box2">Mozilla <br> <i>Choose which program(s) you'd like to run.
> It is possible to run multiple programs at one time!</i></font><br>
> <input type="button" name="btn1" onclick="Button1_OnClick"
> value="Submit"><br> <div id="error"></div>
> 
> 
> 
> </body> </html>
```

This works perfectly as it is supposed to, when i check both programs, both of them will run, when i check one of them, only one will run. But what if i have like 50 different programs on that list? I suppose there is a simplier way to write this than writing load of if/else/elseif statements for each program combination? As mentioned above im complete noob to this, maybe i simply haven't discovered an easier way yet... But that's also why i ask.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the elements attributes for your purpose. 
Iterate over all the checkboxes, then start the process using its path stored in your custom attribute if it's checked. Done.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/vbscript">
        Dim objShell
        Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

        Sub StartProcesses
            Dim Checkbox
            For Each Checkbox In Document.getElementsByName("process")
                If Checkbox.Checked Then
                    objShell.Run """" & Checkbox.getAttribute("path") & """"
                End If
            Next
        End Sub
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <font face=Calibri>
        Check the program you would like to run! <br>
        Available programs to run for now: <br> 
        <div id="ProcessList">
            <input type="checkbox" name="process" path="cmd.exe">CMD <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="process" path="iexplore.exe">Internet Explorer <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="process" path="%programfiles(x86)%\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe">Firefox <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="process" path="calc.exe">Calculator <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="process" path="notepad.exe">Notepad <br>
        </div>
        <i>Choose which program(s) you'd like to run. It is possible to run multiple programs at one time!</i>
    </font><br>
    <input type="button" onclick="StartProcesses" value="Submit"><br>
    <div id="error"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How would you add a MsgBox displaying a warning when none of the checkboxes are checked?

Comment: @WatskeBart have a look at https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e53b5fa495736ea6ba1dfa7dc32370b0